# WiX: How to add the option to Launch on Startup in the ExitDlg?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action, wix3, wix3.7

On the Exit Dialog, I want to add a checkbox so the user can choose to Launch on Startup. Where after 'Finish' is pressed, it will modify the registry for it to start the application when Windows launches. How would I accomplish this?

I don't know if it's possible to integrate the addition of a registry key into a custom action and I can't find anything that says how to do this.

Thanks in advance.